# error cs1001 cant use command ctrl c

Tags: c#

Im trinying to write a word via pressed (ctrl+ c) but not work

please help me

please give me a hand

```
   using System;

           using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    class MainClass 

       {
static void Main()
  {
        ConsoleKeyInfo keypress;
  keypress = Console.ReadKey(); // read keystrokes 

  if (keypress.Key == ConsoleKey.(CTRL-C))
  {
  Console.Write("One ");


}
}
  }
```

Comment: please help me .  cant use this sentence if (keypress.Key == ConsoleKey.(CTRL-C))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Console applications consider CTRL+C to be the "termination command" of which is expected to cease functionality of the application and force it to close. Using CTRL+C as your input keys is faulty to begin with...

HOWEVER...

The keypress.Key should be the C key and you then need to also check if any "modifiers" are pressed. ALT, SHIFT, CTRL are the primary modifier keys and you usually check a boolean value to see if they are pressed or not . . so your application will check to see if the C key is pressed and if the CTRL modifier is pressed as well.

Check this out to get more information:
[How to determine which key modifier is pressed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yazd4ct6(v=vs.110).aspx)